fastboot waiting for device
I checked online and couldn't really get my answer. it was all "it's a driver problem/have you turned USB debugging on?" and stuff like that
but actually to my surprise this is what I get:

so as you can see ADB can recognize my device but not fastboot. by the way I downloaded adb as a ZIP file and added to Path manually
and I also did run commands such as "adb reboot-bootloader / adb reboot bootloader / adb reboot-fastboot" which doesn't seem to work.


Please don't post screenshots of text in a terminal, text should be posted as text. 2. Wrong site, non-programming questions about Android should be posted on https://android.stackexchange.com 3. adb and fastboot are two different modes, either adb or fastboot are active, never both at the same time, see e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221635/2241

